# Passing slice as an IntoIterator

Tags: rust

I have a function with the following signature:

```
pub fn history<'a, I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>>(&self, _: I)
```

Later on, I have a struct with a field called `main` that is a boxed closure.

```
main: box |args: &[&str], shell: &mut Shell| {
    shell.history.history(args);
},
```

The important part is that I am calling the function I showed the signature for with `&[&str]` as an argument. I get the following compile error:

```
src/main.rs:281:47: 281:54 error: type mismatch resolving `<&[&str] as core::iter::IntoIterator>::Item == &str`:
 expected &-ptr,
    found str [E0271]
src/main.rs:281         shell.history.history(args);
```

So apparently `&[&str]` doesn't work as an `IntoIterator`. I tried `shell.history.history(args.into_iter());` and got a similar error message.

Strangely, `shell.history.history(args.iter().map(|s|*s));` does work. This hardly seems like the correct solution though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at [how `IntoIterator` is implemented for slices](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#implementations):

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T]
    type Item = &'a T
    type IntoIter = Iter<'a, T>
    fn into_iter(self) -> Iter<'a, T>
```

Note that `Item` is defined as a *reference* to `T`, where `T` is the type of the items in the slice. Since you have a slice of `&str`, this means that `Item` is `&&str`.

You can use `.map(|s| *s)`, as you tried, to dereference the outer reference and yield an iterator of `&str`.

Another solution is to generalize your `history` function to accept both `I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a str>` and `I: IntoIterator<Item = &'b &'a str>`. In order to do that, we need a trait that both `&'a str` and `&'b &'a str` implement. We can use [`AsRef<str>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) for this (thanks to Vladimir Matveev for pointing this out):

```
pub fn history<I>(i: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    for s in i {
        println!("{}", s.as_ref());
    }
}

fn main() {
    history(&["s"]);
}
```

Comment: @FrancisGagné couldn't `AsRef<str>` be used instead of custom `IntoStrSlice`?

Comment: And indeed, it [does work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7b83be09dcbc22fb3055&version=stable).

Comment: I didn't know `AsRef` could be used like that! Edited.

Comment: Can this be abstracted for any type that implements `AsRef` and say `Debug`?

Comment: @user1685095 `where I::Item: AsRef<str> + Debug`, or do you mean `where I::Item: AsRef<T>, T: Debug` (where `T` is a second generic type)?

Comment: Or the fancy new syntax: `pub fn history(i: impl IntoIterator<Item = impl AsRef<str>>)`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné I wanted to mean that item after transforming to reference can be formatted with debug formatter.

Comment: @user1685095 https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/impl-trait-for-returning-complex-types-with-ease.html